# What is the order of AR and MA?

Tags: arima, autoregressive-models, eviews

I am unable to understand how to choose the order of AR and MA for ARIMA model. I am using Automatic ARIMA forecasting tool of E-views and it gives ARMA(2,4) but the output table shows p-values of these greater than 0.05.

Answer (score 0):

You could take a look at the Information Criterion for different orders (for example in the range of [0, 5] ). The model which minimizes either the AIC or BIC is preferred.